# TypeError: Cannot read property parentNode of null

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my script.

http://danny.b.cmmstudents.nl/MM-4/pages/hardware.html

This is the javascript I am using:

```
var imgPad = "../media/images/";
var canSwap = document.images ? true : false;

var mapAreas = document.getElementsByClassName('iphoneLink');
var eventList = ['mouseover', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart'];
var map = document.getElementById('softwareMap');

var informatieHeading = document.getElementById('informatieHeading');
var informatiePar = document.getElementById('informatiePar');

for(var i=0; i<mapAreas.length; i++){
   for(theEvent of eventList){          
        mapAreas[i].addEventListener(theEvent, function(e){
            if(e.type == 'mouseover'){
                if(map.parentNode.id == "softwareMap"){
                    var checkDb = hwItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].afbeelding;
                    swapImage("mainImg", checkDb); // Perform function 
                } else{
                    var checkDb = swItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].afbeelding;
                    swapImage("mainImg", checkDb); // Perform function 
                } 
            } else if (e.type == 'mouseout'){
                 if(map.parentNode.id == "softwareMap"){
                    swapImage("mainImg", 'iphonex.png'); // Perform function 
                } else{
                    swapImage("mainImg", 'iphonexInside.png'); // Perform function 
                }
            } else if(e.type == 'click'){
                if(map.parentNode.id == "softwareMap"){
                    informatieHeading.textContent = swItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].titel;
                    informatiePar.textContent = swItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].omschrijving;
            } else{
                    informatieHeading.textContent = hwItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].titel;
                    informatiePar.textContent = hwItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].omschrijving;
                }
            } else if (e.type == 'touchstart'){
                informatieHeading.textContent = hwItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].titel;
                informatiePar.textContent = hwItems[this.getAttribute("data-dbId")].omschrijving;  
            };  
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
>       at HTMLAreaElement.

This is the HTML for the hardware page:
And there is the same for softwarepage but there is the id 'softwareMap'

```
<main id="content">
    <div class="iphoneTekst">
      <p>Klik met je vinger op de interactieve iPhone</p>
      <p>Ga met de muis over de interactieve iPhone</p>
    </div>      
   <div id="iphone"><img id="mainImg" src="../media/images/iphonexInside.png" alt="iPhone X" usemap="#hardwareMap" width="772 " height="1472"></div>

    <map id="hardwareMap" name="hardwareMap"><!-- image Map -->
       <area class="iphoneLink" data-dbId="0" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="570,60,706,325">
       <area class="iphoneLink" data-dbId="1" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="59,1209,347,1316">
       <area class="iphoneLink" data-dbId="2" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="498,34,550,114">
       <area class="iphoneLink" data-dbId="3" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="449,1358,678,1433">
       <area class="iphoneLink" data-dbId="4" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="66,235,417,233,420,829,625,837,626,1201,57,1205">
   </map>
   <article id="informatie"><!-- Div wordt ingeladen met info van de iphone-database.js -->
       <div>
           <h2 id="informatieHeading">iPhone X</h2>
           <p id="informatiePar">We hebben altijd al een iPhone willen maken die één en al scherm is. Een iPhone waar je zo in opgaat dat je je er helemaal in verliest. Eentje die zo intelligent is dat hij reageert op een tikje, je stem of zelfs je blik. Met iPhone X hebben we dit doel nu bereikt.<br>Welkom in de toekomst.</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <div class="ctaBackToTop"><a href="#iphone">Back to top</a></div>
</main>
```

Comment: `softwareMap` doesn't exist in your HTML source code.

Comment: Show us the html please.

Comment: I'm looking at your link, I don't see softwareMap anywhere in the console.

Comment: This question posts HTML and JavaScript that the OP states don't actually go together. Until the question is corrected to show code that go together, it makes no sense. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the JavaScript doesn't go with the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is being returned `null`.  `getElementById` returns `null` if is can't find an element with a corresponding id.  A brief look at your page shows that there is no html element on your page with an id of `softwareMap`.  There is however a `hardwareMap`.

When the above code is run on the link to the hardware page, there is no element with an id of softwareMap, there is however on the software page. If you are intending on using the same script above on both pages you should put in an additional test in your if statements to check if map exists. Hence the statement would become `if(map && map.parentNode.id) {...}` That would silence the error.

** Edited to include more deets.

Comment: Hi Lesbaa, There is a mapTag with the id softwareMap and a another page with also a mapTag with id hardwareMap

Comment: @DannyB No, there isn't. This is your `map` tag: `<map id="hardwareMap" name="hardwareMap">`. There is no other `map` tag on that page and no element with an `id` of `softwareMap`.

Comment: Hi Danny, so when the above code is run on the link to the page for `hardwareMap`, there is no element with an id of `softwareMap`.  If you are intending on using the same script above on both pages you should put in an additional test in your if statements to check if `map` exists.  Hence the statement would become `if(map && map.parentNode.id) {...`.  That would silence the error.

Comment: i'm new to javaScript. 
instead of map.parentNode.id == "softwareMap" should I use map.parentNode.id && "softwareMap"?

Comment: @DannyB You don't have anything on that page called `sofwareMap`, so you can't refer to that.

Comment: @DannyB This line is the problem: `var map = document.getElementById('softwareMap');` Since you don't have any element with an `id` of `softwareMap`, your `map` variable is `null`. Later when you write: `map.parentNode.id == "softwareMap"`, it fails with the error you see because you can't call `parentNode` on `map` because `map` is nothing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus there are 2 pages hardware.html and software.html and the id of softwareMap is on software.html and the id hardwareMap is on the hardware.html.

Comment: @DannyB But, the link you posted was to hardware.html and the code you've shown is for software.html. You can't just mix and match them. Why not just show us the HTML and JavaScript that go together? This is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus 
I can still merge the same for loop? that says my teacher 
if 2 events are similar, they can be merged

I'm quite new with JavaScript.
Look at my link: http://danny.b.cmmstudents.nl/MM-4/pages/hardware.html

Comment: @DannyB No, the way your code is right now, it will only work when the `map` `id` is `softwareMap`. Of course, you could rewrite the code to make it so that it would work for both files, but the way you have it now, no, you can't use the same JavaScript for both HTML files. You'd need to add more code that tests to see if the element exists before you use it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Maybe you will help me? what do I have to make of the code?

Comment: @DannyB I've told you several times. You need one of your JS files to have `map` bound to `softwareMap` and another to have `map` bound` to `hardwareMap`. Then each HTML file needs to be connected to the correct corresponding JavaScript file.

Comment: @DannyB Are you serious?! We've all explained very clearly what the problem is and what you need to do to fix it. Don't blame us because your teacher hasn't taught you correctly. You're welcome!

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry but was very frustrated why the weather does not work.
the answer from above (if (map && map.parentNode.id) {...}) I have tried that works on it but get the wrong pictures at the wrong pages

Comment: @DannyB I have told you that you need to use 2 JavaScript files and 2 HTML pages, not the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

`#softwareMap` is not in the DOM.

Edit:
To be precise, the selector `#softwareMap` does not match any element in the DOM when the querySelector method is called. If there is some operation that should place the target element in the DOM, make sure that it is called before you try to access it via selector mentioned.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Ele [Sigh] No. This is the answer. Again, you confuse brevity for a comment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus are you serius bro?

Comment: @Ele Are you bro?

Comment: @ScottMarcus *"It seems"* looks like a guessing, please come on!

Comment: @Ele It's also seems like you don't know the right answer to various questions when they hit you in the face.

Comment: @ScottMarcus what are you talking about? You think this is a game? Did you see the comments?  See the comment, the first one.  Is a fact what I've written.  Come on!

Comment: @Ele You seem to have a problem with sort answers. You confuse them for comments. The reason that this error comes up is because of a `null` reference. Given that the page the the OP points to, doesn't have an element called `softwareMap` in it, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Ele `Short answer != comment` necessarily - no matter how often that is true, it is not always.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm not going to argue with you anymore. Close the conversation.

Comment: @Ele You can stop arguing any time you like. I will not stay silent though when you incorrectly tell people that their answers are not answers. You fundamentally misunderstand what an answer is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Look the new version of this answer? That's brevety well used.  Come on!

Comment: Maybe it really was too short of an answer - in the meantime, I added some more input, maybe it will help the OP to find the issue.

Comment: @Ele You need to stop equating the length of an answer with whether it's an answer. Not all answers require in-depth explanations. This one certainly doesn't. As I've told you before, a comment is something that is tangential to the question or answers. This indicated exactly what the problem was, period.